# Combining Hashes - NTLM and SHA

Tags: hash, sha-256, md5, sha-512

i have been recently learning about different types of hashing and the encryption/decryption methods of such hashes. Im currently trying to find the preimage of this hash i have been given as a homework question.

```
user2222:$6$l4w8Hnu1/ZHGGd.p$BHENd1yKnjRcW.KcAtqcOY096A6HtQBFaWGaXkQ0TofWRy.bngwrVTlLlzdwOLRvHtesGPIrY4LGSUIDnpA9w1:18011:0:99999:7:::
```

However, i am not quite sure what type of hash it is or if it is a combination of multiple. At first glance i believed it to be NTLM due to the username at the start. However if it is split into parts based on fullstops or colons, this is what it looks like:

```
["user2222","$6$l4w8Hnu1/ZHGGd", "p$BHENd1yKnjRcW", "KcAtqcOY096A6HtQBFaWGaXkQ0TofWRy", "bngwrVTlLlzdwOLRvHtesGPIrY4LGSUIDnpA9w1","18011", "0", "99999","7"]
```

As such:

- user2222: i think is the username
- a combination of the middle elements seems to be SHA512-Crypt:

```
$6$l4w8Hnu1/ZHGGd.p$BHENd1yKnjRcW.KcAtqcOY096A6HtQBFaWGaXkQ0TofWRy.bngwrVTlLlzdwOLRvHtesGPIrY4LGSUIDnpA9w1
```

However, i am fairly new to this so im not really sure what all of this means together as i have only really done MD5. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you have been given a hash and do not know where it came from, please do not attempt to crack it.

Comment: @AdrianSelf its just a homework question i am trying to solve

Comment: @BarTM: I find your wording inappropriate. The word *crack* is normal for someone who is doing this *routinely* or at least knows multiple approaches to do that. But if you don't know the basics and are struggling with homework, it is obvious that the word *crack* is just not applicable to you. So please replace *crack* with the wording from your homework like "find preimage". Afterwards I will delete my comment.